# How to write a ajax call for this POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I have not worked on AJAX, I have tried to for a ajax function to POST this below curl,

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
 "replace-field":{
 "name":"sell-by",
 "type":"date",
 "stored":false }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema
```

I have written the below function based on the resources available in SF, but this is not posting the data to the app. It doesn't throw any console error too.

```
 function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema',
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
        },
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
              "replace-field":{
                     "name":"sell-by",
                     "type":"date",
                     "stored":false
                     }
                }),
       success: function (response, status, xhr) {                         
                    if (status == "success") {
                        alert("sucess");
                    } else {
                        alert(status + ' - ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                },
        // processData: false, // this is optional
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf',
        crossDomain: true,
    });
}
```

Comment: are you seeing any error?Also you can change the url method like this
url:"someUrl.urlpattern". This someUrl.urlpattern must be also handled in java class & urlpattern is what you set in web.xml

Comment: Do you have jQuery included on your page?

Comment: Are you sure you need cross-domain?

Comment: Is the AJAX call on the same port as the webserver?

Comment: What error do you get? E.g. is your "server" supporting jsonp ? And if so, is your server returning the request with "?json.wrf=?" ? the jsonp parameter is for saying the script which callback parameter is returned

Comment: This seems like a CORS issue as everyone else pointed out. First of all "origin" headers must be set on the remote service, not in the ajax call itself. +please explain your "jsonp" usage. I don't see any callback function for it to consume.

Comment: AS I mentioned, I dont see any error in the browser console

Comment: @xtreme: Console is not a silver bullet. Look in the network tab to see if the request is endlessly "pending".

Comment: Actually this request is hitting the web app at 8983 port, I can see them in the logs

Comment: @Ingmars Since the Curl has  the --data-binary how should Ajax data type defined?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes I have included and the request from the console is showing 200 OK. I can even see the log of the app in 8983 getting this request but my question now is, am I sending the correct data format ? --data-binary

Comment: @xtreme I'd say use json as data type and make sure your API endpoints has that "access-control..." header. If you need to send some extra binary data, then simply base64 encode it and add as attribute to your ajax post (json) request.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema',
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
        },
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
              "replace-field":{
                     "name":"sell-by",
                     "type":"date",
                     "stored":false
                     }
                },
                success: function (response, status, xhr) {                   

                    if (status == "success") {
                        alert("sucess");

                    } else {
                        alert(status + ' - ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                },
        // processData: false, // this is optional
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf',
        crossDomain: true,
    });
}
```